# angularJs - ngRepeat with custom id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Edit:

So, after messing around with the code and following everyones advice, I found out that, indeed, the id -does- work, but somethign else blocks it.

This is the entire line of code, now: where is the problem located?

```
<tr id="{{item.id}}" 
    ng-mouseover="hovering(item.id)" 
    ng-mouseleave="leaving(item.id)"  
    ng-show="showRow(item)" 
    ng-repeat="item in elements| limitTo: limiter"  
    data-id="{{item.id}}" 
    data-parent="{{item.parent}}">
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in users| limitTo: limiter" id="{{item.id}}">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**DATA:**

```
$scope.users = [
    { id: 1, name: "user", email : ""},
    { id: 2, name: "anotherUser", email: ""}];
```

**Problem:**

the ID stays `"{{item.id}}"` and isn't converted to, eg: "1". I tried with `ng-attr-id` as well, but it didn't work either.

Why isn't the ID `"transformed"` to what it should be?

To bring the problem a bit further: if I do `data-id="{{item.id}}`, it DOES work.

Comment: does `item.id` contains value really?

Comment: it should work if you have `id` property in `item` object

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle

Comment: @pankajparkar It does, I'll add an example of the user-table.

Comment: @Jordumus check errors in console

Comment: The error is somewhere else. It's working fine : http://jsbin.com/dasufunefa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: do you use some 3rd-party libs?

Comment: To bring the problem a bit further: if I do data-id="{{item.id}}, it DOES work.
@Grundy It's a quite large project, but on this page, only bootstrap is included.

Comment: @Jordumus possibly if you provide more code we can help you

Comment: @Jordumus you use this markup directly or as a part for template for some directive?

Comment: @Grundy Updated question with more code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How many time you edit your question man? hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All seems to Work

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.limiter = 4;
      $scope.users = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'n1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'n2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'n3'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'n4'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'n5'
      }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'n6'
      }];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in users| limitTo: limiter" id="{{item.id}}">
    <td>Id - {{item.id}}</td>
    <td>Name - {{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused, your example works as well here, why doesn't mine work.. *goes checking differences*

Comment: @Jordumus check angular version also and errors in console

Comment: Console is error-free, angular should be latest version, but will check.

Comment: @Jordumus latest from `v1.x` or `v2`?

Comment: Running  AngularJS v1.3.14.

Comment: did you call  assign `controller` name and `ng-app` name in you html side?

Comment: @RameshRajendran you ask me or @Jordumus? :-)

Comment: no no , i ask to him. because he may be missed to assign the `controller `and `ng-app` settings .

Comment: @RameshRajendran from edited post: _if I do data-id="{{item.id}}, it DOES work._

Comment: okay any way, Leave your code. You need to just copy and past the code from @Grudy answer

Comment: @RameshRajendran :-D Gru*n*dy

Comment: @RameshRajendran Did as you suggested: just used his code, and it DOES work then.. Problem is: I can't drop all other parts of the code. Updated question?

Comment: My final solution, please try to add `ng-model="item.id"` in your TR tag, then please verify it.

Comment: I copy-pasted each extra attribute, and checked if it kept working in between, now all attributes are added again and it still works. I have no idea why it didn't work before, but I marked this as the answer, because getting back to the roots was what solved it for me in the end.

Answer (score 3):

My previous  answer is very poor, But some one put up vote. lol.

okay finally i got the issue.

You need to change `var users = [...]` to `$scope.users=[...];`

### Update

- Did you assign `controller` and `ng-app` in you html side?
- try to use `$scope.$apply()` in your controller.

  `$scope.users = [
      { id: 1, name: "user", email : ""},
      { id: 2, name: "anotherUser", email: ""}];
  $scope.$apply();`

Comment: @camden_kid that is what i'm thinking

Comment: @RameshRajendran where did you find `var users = [...]` in OP question

Comment: @pankajparkar, it was before my edit. Ramesh: I am using $scope, just didn't copy it, sorry.

Comment: Now he edited him question. but still you can look there

Comment: I'm working on a fiddler, to answer your update: all other angular-stuff works (see also my updated question)

Comment: try to use `$scope.$apply()` in your controller.